# Where do I ask a question about Sales, Distribution Channels and Customers Relationship management?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

In general, I am looking for answers regarding Sales, Distribution Channel Management and Customer Relationship Management.

Specifically, one example of a question would be:

> Under what conditions is it advisable to do:
>
> a) Supply to any distributor who asks for quotations as a producer, 
>   
> *or*
>
> b) Create a hierarchy of suppliers depending on a set of criteria as Customer Segmentation via ABC Analysis suggests.

I found [Startups Stack Exchange](https://startups.stackexchange.com/) and [Economics Stack Exchange](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), but both seem not to hit the nail on the head (read: be the right place to ask). Any guidance? Something like *Management*, *Sales* or *Administration*?

Comment: *advice and insights* sounds as a question that is either broad or opinion based. Those don't fly on many sites. Maybe expand a bit on the exact question you want to ask.

Comment: Rather than stating it only in the title, I think you should include your question in the body because the title should be a summary of that.

Comment: @rene & polygeo, does my edit address your concerns sufficiently?

Comment: It is fairly unlikely that someone will still answer this, right?

Comment: Is there a tumbleweed-badge in "meta", too? :P